# Now I have this api to generate random fox images , how do i download those generated fox (url)

Tags: python, python-requests

This is the api - https://randomfox.ca/floof/

and this is my code :-

```
import requests
import wget

response = requests.get("https://randomfox.ca/floof/")

fox = response.json()
print(fox['image'])
wget.download(fox)
```

Now It outputs a url , now how do i download that generated image , pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, looking at the URL gives me this:

`{"image":"https:\/\/randomfox.ca\/images\/110.jpg","link":"https:\/\/randomfox.ca\/?i=110"}`

When you print `fox['image']`, all you are doing is printing it, but it isn't a variable. To fix this, adjust your code like so:

```
response = requests.get("https://randomfox.ca/floof/")

fox = response.json()
url = fox['image']
wget.download(url)
```

Second, there is no need to use `wget`, as `requests` can handle it all.

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://randomfox.ca/floof/")

fox = response.json()
url = fox['image']
r = requests.get(url)
with open('image.png','wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```